# Format number on Y-axis of Google Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have a web page that displays several Google Charts on a map - http://wa.water.usgs.gov/projects/puyallupgw/hydrographs.htm. On some of the charts, the numbers in the Y-axis have decimals. Can I format these numbers so that they all have the same number of decimal places? I am not able to post an image, but you can go to the web page and select 20N/03E-07Q02 from the dropdown menu. The numbers on the Y-axis are:

28.25
28.5
28.75
29
29.25
...

I'd like to format them so that they are:
28.25
28.50
28.75
29.00
29.25

Is that a possibility?

I am creating these charts using the Image Charts (https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/line_charts).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I just add &chxs=1N*z2* to the URL to format the y-axis to 2 decimal places. https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/line_charts#axis_label_styles